# Why do i get this a compiling error when compiling python to a EXE

Tags: python

when trying to compile python to an EXE (I'm on a mac) using auto-py-to-exe, I get this error message

```
/Users/test/output/search_main ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search_main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/8w/zsdp6g8n0y56n_5j8_79ldw00000gn/T/pip-unpacked-wheel-5JwU3T/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 391, in load_module
  File "site-packages/tkinter/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/8w/zsdp6g8n0y56n_5j8_79ldw00000gn/T/pip-unpacked-wheel-5JwU3T/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 391, in load_module
  File "lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/8w/zsdp6g8n0y56n_5j8_79ldw00000gn/T/pip-unpacked-wheel-5JwU3T/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 680, in load_module
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/8w/zsdp6g8n0y56n_5j8_79ldw00000gn/T/_MEISNfraO/_tkinter.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/Tcl
  Referenced from: /var/folders/8w/zsdp6g8n0y56n_5j8_79ldw00000gn/T/_MEISNfraO/_tkinter.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/folders/8w/zsdp6g8n0y56n_5j8_79ldw00000gn/T/_MEISNfraO/Tcl: not a file
    /private/var/folders/8w/zsdp6g8n0y56n_5j8_79ldw00000gn/T/_MEISNfraO/Tcl: not a file
[86672] Failed to execute script search_main
```

Comment: Is the meaning of this message itself clear to you?

Comment: No, not at all.